# SpringBoot: Create document in mongodb on startup if not exists

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, aws-documentdb

I have a small service on SpringBoot and Mongodb as a DB.
I need to be able create a small collection with one document ( very basic: id, name, status) on startup. An analog of sql create table if not exists, but for mongo. How do I do that?
I tried to initialize values in the document attributes, but it didn't help.
Currently, collection and the document appear  only if I use API to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use something like [`ApplicationRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) or [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) which can be defined as a bean.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initialize(MyRepository myRepository) {

        return args -> {
            // Insert elements into myRepository 
        };
    }
}
```

Both `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationRunner` are functional interfaces, so we can use a lambda for them. Spring Boot will execute them at the startup of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the spring internal event mechanism.
When your application is ready, spring triggers the event `ApplicationReadyEvent`

You can listen to this event and init your collection:

```java
@Component
public class DataInit implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    public DataInit(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // init data
    }
}
```